# How to make photoshop cs5 launch faster

Tags: windows-7, performance, photoshop-cs5

I have a reasonably fast computer with Core 2 Quad Q8200 CPU, 4 GB ram, Seagate 7200 rpm drive. But when I open Photoshop it takes about 15 seconds to open and additional 8 sec to become responsive.

I want some suggestion to make the launch faster.

Comment: Buy an SSD. It will open much faster. Here lemme try.

Comment: Under two seconds...

Comment: i know what SSDs are meant for. But i want to know how to make launch fast on my existing machine.

Comment: @kaykay, I know, that's why it was a comment, not an answer. BTW, what operating system are you running?

Comment: @Yar i am running windows 7 64-bit and photoshop cs5 64-bit

Comment: Try 32-bit to see if it's the same result? I hate to say it, it's not what you want to hear but it really is a hardware thing I'm guessing. My last system was clean, had the right settings, and wasn't that far off from your specs, and photoshop took forever. New system is core i5 + SSD. SSD especially makes a huge difference. I don't think there's a magic bullet that can get photoshop where you want it. Even if you cut the time in half it'd still feel like a while.

Answer (score 0):

Check your 'Scratch Disk Settings' in Edit > Preferences

The primary scratch disk drive should have decent amount of free space, add some secondary drives as scratch disks

It should run faster now !!!

Comment: it will not help in making the launch faster. because i have already make the scratch disk on the RAM through ramdisk. it will only help after the photoshop load and it need more memory then the memory assigned to photoshop

Answer (score 0):

When using another Adobe Product, Premiere, I've enhanced performance all around by increasing my page file size. See if that helps you.